# Angular - Call back to parent component using @Output and Promises

Tags: angular

I want to be able to subscribe to the onSearch @Output of the child-component so that when ever a search is performed in the child component a promise to return the data from the search is handled in the parent component. Is there a way to do this in Angular? I have tried making onSearch an @Input, and that works for returning a promise, but "this" scope is the child component. So I think it has to be an @oOutput

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component-search',
  templateUrl: './child-component.html'
})
export class ChildSearchComponent{
  public data : any = new Array();
  @Output() onSearch: any = new EventEmitter();
  search(form: any) {
      let self = this
      this.onSearch.emit({searchText:"Text"}).then(res=>{
        self.data = res;
      },rej=>{})
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component-search',
  template: `
    <child-component-search (onSearch)="search($event)"></child-component-search>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent{
  constructor(public service: MyService){}
  search(search: any) {
      let self = this
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        this.service(search.searchText).then(res=>{
            resolve(res)
        },rej=>{})
      })
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you're using a `let this = self`. You're in typescript so this is handled for you ;). Also, your problem might simply come from `this.service(...)` because `this.service` is not a function, it's a class so you need to call the function from it.

Answer (score 2):

I've achieved this by passing a callback function:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component-search',
  templateUrl: './child-component.html'
})
export class ChildSearchComponent{
  public data : any = new Array();

  @Input() onSearch: Function;
  search(form: any) {

      this.onSearch({searchText:"Text"}, res => {
        this.data = res;
      });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component-search',
  template: `
    <child-component-search [onSearch]="onSearch"></child-component-search>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent{
  constructor(public service: MyService){}

  onSearch = (search: any, callback) => {

      this.service(search.searchText).then(res=>{
          callback(res)
      },rej=>{});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component-search',
  templateUrl: './child-component.html'
})
export class ChildSearchComponent{
  @Input() data; // use this data in the template
  @Output() onSearch = new EventEmitter<{searchText:string}>();

  search(form: any) {
      this.onSearch.emit({searchText:"Text"});
  }
}
```

parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component-search',
  template: `
    <child-component-search (onSearch)="search($event)" [data]='data'>
    </child-component-search>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  data:any[] = [];

  constructor(public service: MyService){}

  search(search: any) {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        this.service(search.searchText).then( res =>{
            this.data = res; // assuming the service will return array
        });
      })
}
```

i use the data came from the parent as an input in the child component, and when the child component search for something you emit an event with the Text searched for, then you handle it in the parent component and update the data property which goes to the child as an input.

in other words,

**Parent** => input(data) => **Child** 
**Child** => emit(search) => **parent**    
// which update input(data) and reflect it in
 the child.

Comment: you don't need to use promises in this case :).